# Is there anything bad about attaching a variable to a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some Javascript code and I need to keep track of a global state. The state is only ever changed by a single function, but it needs to be widely accessible from other functions.

I'm currently doing it in this manner:

```
function foo(bar) {
    var self = arguments.callee;
    if (!self.state) {
        self.state = 0; // called 0 times
    } else {
        self.state++; // increase the number of times i've been called
    }
}
```

Is it sensible to bind the global state variable to the function like this? It's nifty but I'm worried that there's something dangerous that I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with assigning properties to function objects. What you should worry about is that `arguments.callee` is deprecated in ECMAScript 5, which is the most recent language specification that's currently making its way into the mainstream browsers. In strict mode, referring to `arguments.callee` will give an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. People do it all the time with constructor functions. A built-in example would be `String.fromCharCode`

If however other functions don't need to reference the state, I would prefer doing the following:

```
var foo = (function () {
  var state = 0;
  return function (bar) {
    state++;
  };
}) ();
```

Even if they do need to reference it, I would probably try to make the above code work in some way. Or even use objects and avoid the singleton-like usage.

Answer (score 1):

I've done things like this before.  I think it is slightly messy, but it won't cause World War III.

Instead of doing this, could you define that function inside a closure, and have the 'state' variable local to that closure?

```
var foo = (function() {
  var state = 0;
  return function(bar) {
    state++;
  };
}());

foo(bar);
```

Comment: The OP said that the state variable needs to be accessible from other functions. You could add a "getter" accessible via the inner function, but that would be messy.

Comment: I presumed that the return value of foo(bar) would be, or incorporate, the state.  Note that neither the OP or my example show foo(bar) returning a value but you could imagine this.

Comment: So you would need to invoke the function just to read the state? What if the function includes other side-effects (such as incrementing the call counter, just for starters)?

Comment: Like I said, that's what I presumed that the purpose of the function was.  If not, you could I suppose define all the other functions that need to read this state in the same scope, or if you need a separate getter you could define and return that as part of an object.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, except that your state variable will never be > 0.  Try this instead:

```
function foo(bar) {
    var self = arguments.callee;
    if (!self.state) { // Or, as trinithis suggested: if (self.state === undefined) {
        self.state = 1; // called once
    } else {
        self.state++; // increase the number of times i've been called
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. That's not actually the code I'm using, but you've got sharp eyes.

Comment: Oh I see. I would instead prefer using `if (self.state === undefined)`.

Comment: The point is that !self.state evaluates to 1 if self.state is 0, so you never get to the "else" part of the logic.

Comment: I think trinithis was suggesting that edit to my version of the function.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I must have edited at the same time as Ouyang posted his comment.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a public field, you could make the counter read-only. Assuming you want to count calls to multiple functions, you could even define a utility method to wrap functions with this behaviour:

```
function countCallsToFunc(func) {
  var count = 0;
  var self = function() {
    count++;
    func.apply(this, arguments);
  };
  self.getCount = function() {
    return count;
  };
  return self;
}

var foo = countCallsToFunc(function(bar) {
  // do something
});

foo();
foo();
alert(foo.getCount());
```